# How to make Responsive button with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm Trying to have submit button center the page.
my code in html is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="margin-right:0;margin-left:0">


<form method="POST"
      action="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/redirect_uri=http://hanie-asemi.ir/laravel/public/instagram/test&response_type=code">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I give the submit button center in desktop but this button Not at the center in mobile!what can I do to centered button in mobile?

Comment: use media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: rows must be followed by cols. Also, you are probably messing something up with those margin-right and left 0. To center the button wrap it in a div with class="text-center"

Comment: can you fiddle here

Comment: @yBrodsky your mean that I create a div with text-center class?margi-right and margin-left are in row div

Comment: @ChandraShekhar what?

Comment: @Honey make use of jsfiddle.net or codepen.io and try to replicate the issue you are currently facing.

Comment: add style="text-align:center" to the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

For this the **CSS** should be

```
submit {
    display:block; /*setting the display to block(auto margin only work's on 
    this case)*/
    margin: auto; /*centering*/
    width: 8%; /*choosing the width*/
}
```

Comment: don't Work for me

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap 2.3.0 you can use `.text-center`, like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-right:0;margin-left:0">


    <form method="POST" action="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/redirect_uri=http://hanie-asemi.ir/laravel/public/instagram/test&response_type=code">
      {{csrf_field()}}

      <div class="row text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will expand my comment. This is the right way:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <form method="POST">
        {{csrf_field()}}

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you have a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/en15xrh6/1/

A `row` should be always followed by some `col-*` class. Touching the css of `row` or `col` classes, for margin or padding **almost** always ends up breaking bootstrap. To do that you have to go to bootstrap source and modify the right variable.

Finally, bootstrap has utility classes: `text-right`, `text-center`, `text-left`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with pure CSS (flexbox):

wrap your button with a div, add a class called `centered` with style:

```
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-right:0;margin-left:0">


    <form method="POST" action="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/redirect_uri=http://hanie-asemi.ir/laravel/public/instagram/test&response_type=code">
      {{csrf_field()}}

      <div class="centered">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```